# Chrome App webview 'loadstop' event firing twice

Tags: webview, google-chrome-app

I create a webview in a Chrome Packaged app and listen for the 'loadstop' event with

```
my_webview.addEventListener('loadstop' ... )
```

It seems to fire twice. Not a disaster, but it seems inefficient and I would like to know why it is doing this, or if I should be looking for something wrong with my code.

Comment: Fires twice when you do what?

Answer (score 0):

`loadstop` fires whenever a page finishes loading. If it seems to fire twice for the same page, maybe that page is redirecting to another page, causing two loads?

Answer (score 0):

Just quoting [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#event-loadstop):

> This event fires every time the number of document-level loads transitions from one (or more) to zero. For example, if a page that has already finished loading (i.e., `loadstop` already fired once) creates a new iframe which loads a page, then a second `loadstop` will fire when the iframe page load completes. This pattern is commonly observed on pages that load ads.

Comment: This could be it. I will have to do some more investigation when I have more time.